# How to open up firewall for incoming Remote Desktop connections in Win 7?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, firewall

How do you open the `Win 7` Firewall for incoming `Remote Desktop` connections?

I get this message in `System Properties`:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is automatically created when you allow remote users.

Click Start -> Right click on Computer and select properties.

Then select Advanced System Protection. Click on the remote tab and enable it. The rule is automatically created for you.

---

Typically, the port used is 3389 so you may want to open that, or in your firewall, choose the RDP program.

---

Lastly

```
Click the Start button Picture of the Start button, click Control Panel, type "firewall" in the search box, and then click Windows Firewall.

Click Allow a program or feature through Windows Firewall.

Under Allowed programs and features, scroll down to Remote Desktop and make sure its check box is selected.

Under Home/Work (Private), make sure the check box next to Remote Desktop is selected.
```

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/allow-remote-desktop-connections-from-outside-your-home-network)

Comment: When I do that I get `You must enable the Windows Firewall exception for Remote Desktop` in `System Properties`. See image above.

Comment: When you do which? I gave 3 options. check out the 3rd option :)

Comment: When I tried the third option `Remote Desktop` was not one of the listed programs.

Comment: @CJ7 Does you computer have a password?

Comment: Yes it does have a password.  I think a recent Windows Update may have altered the firewall settings.

Comment: You can roll it back. Or, check if your PC is designed for a Public Network or Local network etc.

Comment: @CJ7 did you ever find a solution for this?  I have the same problem (Remote Desktop is simply not an option listed in windows firewall)

Comment: This is quite an old question but perhaps for the commenters (and googlers) still useful: RDP does *NOT* work for the Windows Home Editions (including premium)! You have to upgrade your windows or use a third-party tool instead. The last comments looked much like "home users", so this might help you, guys